# How do I indicate a line using MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

I couldn't find this in the MathJax tutorial or through Google. Apologies if I missed it somewhere obvious.

Say I have two points $P_1$ and $P_2$ and I want to express the line defined by them.  If I was writing, e.g. a geometry proof, I would write it like this:

```
<----->
  P1P2
```

How do I write this in MathJax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\overleftrightarrow{P_1P_2}` produces
$$
\overleftrightarrow{P_1P_2}
$$
There are also `\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}` and `\overleftarrow{P_1P_2}` that produce
$$
\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}\quad\text{and}\quad\overleftarrow{P_1P_2}
$$
Without arrowheads, there is also `\overline{P_1P_2}` that produces
$$
\overline{P_1P_2}
$$